# SVN files edited thru FTP, How do I fix the edited files so they work thru SVN again?

Tags: svn, ftp

Basically, a 3rd party analyst we brought on to make some improvements to our site decided to edit files directly on the live server through FTP. Any time we make changes to those pages through SVN, we have PHP parse errors.

Things should be edited through the SVN and committed. We have our working copies setup so we can edit them how ever we want while having them running under Apache for testing. We commit all of our changes to a local repository, then commit from there to the live server.

The code on the live server that causes the parse error has `>>>>> .mine` and `>>>>> .rxxxx`. How can I revert those files back to before they were edited through FTP so I can update them through SVN again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have some conflicts, [this site](http://ariejan.net/2007/07/04/how-to-resolve-subversion-conflicts/) may help.

Comment: Thanks for that, we ended up making everything work from ftp, and then committing the live server to our local server and then committing that back to the live server which fixed all of the conflicts and allowed us to make changes thru SVN again.

We didn't have any changes on the local repo, so merging things there worked without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to delete everything and check out a fresh copy.

Comment: Well, having to deal with the symlinking, configuration files, image folder(8gb), and some other things not versioned, committing back to our local repo and then committing that back to the live server was the simplest thing to do. Your solution was next on the list if that didn't work. Thanks for the quick reply too!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a svn revert on you server working copy?

```
svn revert -R
```